# Настроить редирект: если нет изображения, то вместо него поставить другое (заглушку "no_image")

Tags: редирект, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Здравствуйте! В каталоге интернет-магазина попадаются товары без фотографий. Чтобы вручную не проставлять для них картинку "Нет фото" нужно сделать редирект в .htaccess, чтобы вместо отсутствующего фото ставилась заглушка "no_image.jpg". Как это можно сделать?

Или, может быть, есть какой-то другой способ решить эту задачу?

Comment: Какая CMS?

Comment: nginx - установлен?

Comment: CMS WordPress, насчёт nginx не могу ответить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте, как тут: http://searchengines.guru/showthread.php?t=393426

Comment: Спасибо! Этот вариант подошёл, no_image поставилась.

Comment: Не за что :)

Comment: @Stuf, Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.